# Lambda querying Redshift: Nothing Happening

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, boto3

I'm having difficulty finding out why there's no changes/actions happening on my redshift cluster even I'm getting a response like this in Cloudwatch.

> {'ClusterIdentifier': 'redshift-chan-dev',
> 'CreatedAt': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 28, 8, 57, 9, 208000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),'Database': 'dev', 'Id': '5d5c7b4c-31e6-41c3-991e-f76383d46775','SecretArn': 'REDSHIFT/dev/chan', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId':'5d5c7b4c-31e6-41c3-991e-f76383d46775', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200,'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '5d5c7b4c-31e6-41c3-991e-f76383d46775', 'content-type':'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '163', 'date': 'Wed, 28 Dec 202208:57:09 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

boto3 'redshift-data' api execution code:

```
response = REDSHIFT_CLIENT.batch_execute_statement( \
        Database = "dev", \
        SecretArn = 'REDSHIFT/dev/chan', \
        ClusterIdentifier = 'redshift-chan-dev', \
        Sqls = [
            drop_tmp_table,
            create_tmp_table,
            copy_to_tmp_table,
            load_tmp_to_winloss,
        ]
    )
```

**QUERIES**

*create_tmp_table*

```
create_tmp_table = """CREATE TABLE dev.schema.table( \
id INT, \
transaction_code VARCHAR, \
"type" VARCHAR, \
org_id SMALLINT, \
region VARCHAR, \
..
```

*copy_to_tmp_table*

```
copy_to_tmp_table = """COPY dev.schema.table \
FROM 's3://{bucket}/{TMP_PREFIX}/{file_name}.csv' \
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::560762403195:role/redshift_copyS3' \
FORMAT AS CSV \
IGNOREHEADER 1"""
```

Comment: Did you COMMIT the actions?

Comment: Im using the 'redshift-data' client for boto3..`REDSHIFT_CLIENT.batch_execute_statement()` Not sure if I need to add commit

Comment: I'm not expert on Data API but it couldn't hurt.  Since this is Data API the results be rolled back if any statement in the batch has an error.  Did you check the success of the statements using describe_statement() call?

Comment: Will try that. Earlier, I tried to pause the redshift cluster and triggered the lambda function.  Error happening is `[ERROR] ValidationException: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the BatchExecuteStatement operation: Redshift cluster status 'PAUSED' is not allowed.`

Comment: I think you are reporting that if the cluster is paused that the Data API call would fail.  Correct me if I got this wrong.  While true this doesn't mean that if the SQL in the batch has an error that the API call would fail.  In the first case the API call couldn't occur, in the second what the API call is initiating fails.  The call can be successful and the SQL fail.  Checking the status of the SQL is needed to know if it completed successfully.  You can check the status of the SQL from inside of Redshift but I expect making the status API call is easier for you to make.

Comment: Include describe_statement() call and here's the error. 'Error': 'FATAL: password authentication failed for user "masteruser"'.

Comment: Thanks @BillWeiner. Already found the fix. Using the describe_statement, I found out that the secrets I'm using is not aligned with the users I have in my redshift cluster

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding describe_statement() call with my lambda function. It shows the "Error" happening when trying to process the sql statements in redshift-data api.

Apparently, it's with the Secret ARN I am using. Should make sure that the credentials of ARN is same with the user I have in the redshift cluster

Thanks for the help @Bill Weiner